# How to configure vimdiff

Tags: vim

I am getting error when I use vimdiff command.

`E91: 'shell' option is empty`

Is there any configuration I have to do in order to user this command like setting DISPLAY?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: What's the full command line when you call vimdiff?

Answer (score 2):

You'll get the answer by typing:

```
:help E91
```

Vim is very well documented. You can generally find answers using `:help` or `:helpgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the shell option. I have

```
:set shell=/bin/bash
```